# enabling mysqli extension on centos server

Tags: centos, mysql, php5

I want to enable `mysqli extension` on Centos server where PHP 5 is installed. After searching online, I saw many 
people talking about uncommenting `mysqli` related line in the `php.ini` and I couldn't find anything 
related to mysqli in my `php.ini` file.

The following returns nothing : `php -m | grep mysqli`

How can I trouble shoot this problem?

Answer (score 7):

Have you installed mysqli? If not, you'll need to run:

yum install php-mysqli

If that doesn't work anymore, you could try easyapache and select mysqli.

Answer (score 2):

PHP installation does not include the support for MySQL database by default, so you need to install `php-mysql` package.

```
The php-mysql package contains a dynamic shared object that will add
MySQL database support to PHP.
```

Do it either from `root` account

```
$ su
# yum install php-mysql
```

or using sudo

```
 $ sudo yum install php-mysql
```

Then run again

```
php -m | grep mysqli
```

Everything should be fine. If the problem persists, make sure that file `/etc/php.d/mysqli.ini` has the following lines

```
# cat /etc/php.d/mysqli.ini 
; Enable mysqli extension module
extension=mysqli.so
```

p.s. Just for reference, my `/etc/php.ini` (i am using CentOS 6.9) has the following settings for MySQLi

```
[MySQLi]
; Maximum number of links.  -1 means no limit.
mysqli.max_links = -1
mysqli.default_port = 3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect = Off
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer Linux version

`sudo dnf install php-mysqli`

Greetings.